# I'm looking for a specific type of Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking for a jquery plugin slider that can do something like this:

http://hitmo-studio.com/contact.html#business-query
(please look at the budget slider)

I'm not sure how do you call this type of slider so I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: I think this is no slider, this is simply an ul floated to the left with an animation when you click something different !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.slider li').click(function(){  
  var liPos = $(this).position().left;
  $('.slibox').stop(1).animate({left:liPos},800);
});
```

## *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ekasac/)*

---

And just with a slight modification you can dynamically change the box width:

```
$('.slider li').click(function(){      
  var liPos = $(this).position().left;
  var liW = $(this).outerWidth(true);
  $('.slibox').stop(1).animate({ left: liPos, width: liW },600);      
});
```

## *[jsBin demo2](http://jsbin.com/ekasac/4/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Now you can learn easily how to upgrade it from this point on (height adjustments...)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your help, code runs beautifully

Comment: @mr1031011 You're welcome! I'm really glad it was easy to understand the simplicity. (No plugin required.)